# How to run Wordpress using two databases

Tags: php, database, wordpress, webserver, hosting

**Service Provider:** Godaddy

**CMS:** Wordpress

**Maximum Database Size Allowed:** 1GB

Recently i got message from my hosting provider saying that my shared hosting database maximum size could be 1GB only, and they want me reduce the size of database for not closing the database because of the over-sized database voilation it. If i can't reduce it then they are asking to shift it to VPS. But VPS is too expensive for me, also, i don't want to change my website IP Address, that will happen if i switch to any other service provider or even to a VPS. Because ppl say that changing IP Address, affects SEO.

Now what i want to know, if it possible to use WordPress with two databases, as i am having more free databases with this service provider, and have almost 20 more databases. So if i could keep one database as my previous one and another one as new, this will solve my problem.

But is that possible?

Comment: Let me say it this way. If you have a site that takes up over 1GB in db size, then you really need to switch to VPS. ( or clean out the trash ).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using HyperDB.

More information can be found here:

> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11154/split-wp-install-between-2-databases

Comment: This is cool, but might not work for the OP's shared hosting scenario. (Then again, it might.)

Comment: Yeah i'll be giving it a try, looks decent. I'll update as soon i get it up and running. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> But is that possible?

It's kind of possible, but you'd have to set up a completely new Wordpress install.

It's not possible to connect the same WP install to two databases.

Comment: That said, I'm having a really hard time imagining how a 1GB database could get filled up in WordPress. What are you doing with it, are you storing images in there?